# Is it possible to install bottom launcher on Debian 7

Tags: debian, gnome, desktop

I want to install Debian 7 on a laptop and have tried to read some information about this platform.

On this review, [Review Debian Squeeze 6.0.5 : The Father of Linux Distro](http://mylinuxexplore.blogspot.in/2012/06/debian-father-of-linux-distro.html) , I saw the last slide with the bottom application launcher:

[image: debian 6]

I wondering how do I configure it in Debian 7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From speed reading the blog, it seems that the launcher at the bottom of the image is called "docky".

Docky 2,1,4-1 is in debian 7.

To install you need to run `apt-get install docky` as root.

This can be done by typing, at the command prompt:

`sudo apt-get install docky` -- if you have sudo privileges,

or

`su` to become root followed by `apt-get install docky` -- if you know the root password.

Comment: On debian you need to use `su` to gain root privileges as `sudo` is not installed by default.

Comment: @casey Sorry my bad. I set up sudo years ago, and forgot.

Comment: @richard Can you recommend how to configure Debian for better usage?

Comment: That question is a bit general. I would stick with the default, for a bit.